# Unable to load FFMPEG library "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:"

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, ffprobe, ffmpeg-php, pyffmpeg

I am trying to build and run old ffmpeg project which, it was in eclipse and now i am trying to run it from Android studio, but app crash displaying below error.

```
2020-01-25 11:57:52.621 26360-26360/org.lance.ffplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.lance.ffplayer, PID: 26360
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "./obj/local/armeabi/libffmpeg.so" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
    at org.lance.ffplayer.FFmpeg.<clinit>(FFmpeg.java:17)
    at org.lance.ffplayer.FFmpeg.getInstance(FFmpeg.java:87)
    at org.lance.ffplayer.FileBrowser.<init>(FileBrowser.java:41)
    at org.lance.ffplayer.UIActivity.onCreate(UIActivity.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3101)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:974)
```

Below are configuration of my project,

[Android studio configuration image link - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv4z6.png)

[Android studio configuration image link - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fPiq.png)

I have spent my entire day to solve this issue but everything failed. Anybody has idea about what i am missing and doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solve your problem ?